# Filter google places API search results iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm looking to filter my near by location searches to restaurants only in the google places API in swift I found tags on googles website https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types but I don't know how to implement these tags any help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class PlacesViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// An array to hold the list of possible locations.
var likelyPlaces: [GMSPlace] = []
var selectedPlace: GMSPlace?

// Cell reuse id (cells that scroll out of view can be reused).
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Register the table view cell class and its reuse id.
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
cellReuseIdentifier)

// This view controller provides delegate methods and row data for the 
table view.
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

tableView.reloadData()
}

// Pass the selected place to the new view controller.
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "unwindToMain" {
  if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? MapViewController {
    nextViewController.selectedPlace = selectedPlace
  }
 }
 }
 }

// Respond when a user selects a place.
extension PlacesViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
selectedPlace = likelyPlaces[indexPath.row]
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMain", sender: self)
}
}

// Populate the table with the list of most likely places.
extension PlacesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
return likelyPlaces.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
let collectionItem = likelyPlaces[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.text = collectionItem.name

return cell
}

// Adjust cell height to only show the first five items in the table
// (scrolling is disabled in IB).
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return self.tableView.frame.size.height/5
}

 // Make table rows display at proper height if there are less than 5 
 items.
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection 
section: Int) -> CGFloat {
if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
  return 1
}
return 0
}
}
```

my other view controller

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  var currentLocation: CLLocation?
  var mapView: GMSMapView!
  var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
  var zoomLevel: Float = 15.0

  // An array to hold the list of likely places.
  var likelyPlaces: [GMSPlace] = []

  // The currently selected place.
  var selectedPlace: GMSPlace?

  // A default location to use when location permission is not granted.
  let defaultLocation = CLLocation(latitude: -33.869405, longitude: 
  151.199)

  // Update the map once the user has made their selection.
  @IBAction func unwindToMain(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // Clear the map.
    mapView.clear()

    // Add a marker to the map.
    if selectedPlace != nil {
      let marker = GMSMarker(position: 
  (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!)
      marker.title = selectedPlace?.name
      marker.snippet = selectedPlace?.formattedAddress
      marker.map = mapView
    }

    listLikelyPlaces()
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialize the location manager.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.delegate = self

    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

    // Create a map.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                          longitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                                          zoom: zoomLevel)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    // Add the map to the view, hide it until we've got a location update.
    view.addSubview(mapView)
    mapView.isHidden = true

    listLikelyPlaces()
  }

  // Populate the array with the list of likely places.
  func listLikelyPlaces() {
    // Clean up from previous sessions.
    likelyPlaces.removeAll()

    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        print("Current Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
      }

      // Get likely places and add to the list.
      if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods {
        for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {
          let place = likelihood.place
          self.likelyPlaces.append(place)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  // Prepare the segue.
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToSelect" {
      if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? PlacesViewController {
        nextViewController.likelyPlaces = likelyPlaces
      }
    }
  }
}

// Delegates to handle events for the location manager.
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  // Handle incoming location events.
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
    print("Location: \(location)")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                          longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,
                                          zoom: zoomLevel)

    if mapView.isHidden {
      mapView.isHidden = false
      mapView.camera = camera
    } else {
      mapView.animate(to: camera)
    }

    listLikelyPlaces()
  }

  /k/ Handle authorization for the location manager.
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .restricted:
      print("Location access was restricted.")
    case .denied:
      print("User denied access to location.")
      // Display the map using the default location.
      mapView.isHidden = false
    case .notDetermined:
      print("Location status not determined.")
    case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
      print("Location status is OK.")
    }
  }

  // Handle location manager errors.
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("Error: \(error)")
  }
    }
```

Comment: You need to append a query item for `type` such as `&type=restaurant` to the `URL` request, the documentation shows an example `URL` request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: Is that for iOS ?

Comment: All `URL`s (i.e. web address) have a defined format independent of operating system.

Comment: But I'm programming in swift in Xcode For a iOS application not for a mobile site

Comment: I'm new to the google places API I think I'm missing something

Comment: The format is the same regardless of web or mobile (iOS/Android). Maybe it would help if you post some code showing how you are creating your `URL` then we could be of more help?

Comment: okay thank you for the help i updated my question with my code.

Comment: Do you have any networking code? How does the array `var likelyPlaces: [GMSPlace] = []` get populated? It is currently set as an empty array.

Comment: I'm not sure i just added the rest of my code i'm using the sample code i got off the google api website

Comment: I sifted through the code you posted and it looks like it is Google's sample code which is not designed to find places near a user's location. I think the sample code you need is found in `GMSPlacePickerViewController` at https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker.

Comment: The code I'm using works perfect for finding places near the current user location the only problem I have is limiting the search to just the near by restaurants

Comment: From what I read in the documentation, the `placeLikelihoodList` is supposed to represent possible user locations, and they choose the place that represents their actual location. I did not see anyway in the `GMSPlacesClient` to search for locations by type.

Answer (score 0):

The GMSPlace class has a var **types** when you can check for restaurant entries. Modifying your code:

```
func listLikelyPlaces() {
    likelyPlaces.removeAll()
    
    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { [weak self] (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if let error = error {
            print("Current Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods {
            for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {
                let place = likelihood.place
                if let types = place.types, types.contains("restaurant") {
                    self.likelyPlaces.append(place)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/supported_types to check the entire list of supported types